# Image not showing from "http" URL in daimajia Slide View Layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, slideshow

```
for (i in 0 until imagesArray.length()) {
            
                val imageRes = imagesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_url")
                Log.e(TAG, "setImageSlider_466: "+imageRes)
                val slide = TextSliderView(this).image(imageRes)
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside)
                    .empty(R.drawable.no_image_placeholder)
                image_slider.addSlider(slide)

                val scaledSlide = DialogTouchImageSlider(this, R.drawable.no_image_placeholder)
                    .description("Description")
                    .image(imageRes).setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside)
                    .empty(R.drawable.no_image_placeholder)
                dialogSlider.addSlider(scaledSlide)
                slide.setOnSliderClickListener {
                    if (disableSliderTouch)
                        return@setOnSliderClickListener

                    dialogSlider.currentPosition = i
                    imageDialog.show()
                }
            }
```

I'm using SliderLayout of daimajia to show image in SlideView from API, but some image containing "http" url which is not showing, it will showing only when image url contain "https" into url, I already checked with Glide and Picasso to show this image.

I want to show image with http URL also.

Comment: Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to application tag in manifest file.

Comment: @blackapps, android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" already added in manifest and also tried with network_security_config.xml. For now I only handling http image with placeholder only https images are showing currently.